# Error when compiling Less in Gulp: `File not found with singular glob`

Tags: npm, gulp, less

I'm working on a legacy site that has some pre-set-up Gulp commands.

I want to compile some .less files into .css. The existing script is as such:

```
gulp.task('less', function(){
  return gulp.src('./src/css/less/app.less')
  .pipe(less({
    paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'))
});
```

However, when I run this I get an error:

```
Error: File not found with singular glob: /src/css/less/app.less (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
```

I've checked all paths, all `@import` and directories and they're all ok.

I am using Gulp Local: 4.0.0, CLI: 2.3.0.

Would anyone know could be causing this?

Comment: That path should be relative to your gulpfile.js.  Is it?

Comment: @Mark Doh! It wasn't! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe later, but Gulp 4 has a new syntax for writing tasks.
Also, you have to fix the wrong path to the source file:

```js
    // gulpfile.js
    const SRC = 'src';
    const DIST = 'src';

    function lessTask(cb) {
        return src(SRC + '/less/app.less')
            .pipe(less())
            .pipe(dest(DIST + '/style.css'));
    }

    exports.default = series(lessTask);
```

```sh
    # On terminal:
    gulp
```